# UITableviewCell dynamic height issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, autolayout

Hello I have one label inside tableview cell, height of label is changed according to content, so after setting try I am trying to calculate height by following code

```
CGSize cellSize = [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
CGFloat height = cellSize.height;
```

but height is always returned as 0, can any one help me to correct this ?

You can see the code here https://github.com/iamabhiee/Github

Comment: Show your cell xib file or .m file where you create constrains

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski you can see the code here https://github.com/iamabhiee/Github

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ 
CGFloat width=[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
//width - rigth and left constraints 8
NSString* strText = @"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum";

NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17] forKey: NSFontAttributeName];

CGRect frame = [strText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(width - 8 - 8, 3000) options:NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine|NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:attributesDictionary context:nil];
// 16 for bottom and top space
return frame.size.height + 16;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for a better solution as I will have multiple type of tableviewcell

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong constrains and missing bottom constrain + you are missing preferred width for UILabel.
Take a look at my screenshot - it works after those fixes.

[image: fix]